# C++ program doesn't scale

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a simple small piece of code which modifies a 2D vector in parallel. I tested it using 1 and 4 threads respectively. However, I just get less than 2 times speed up. I can't think of any reason why it doesn't scale. Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<vector>
#include<chrono>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;

struct Dummy{
    char dummy[70];
    Dummy(){
        for(int i=0;i<70;i++){
            dummy[i]='a';
    }
    }
};

int main(){
    int num = 5000000;
    vector<vector<Dummy> >myvec(4, vector<Dummy>(num));

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ //modifies myvec in parallel
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread %d is going to work\n",tid);
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
            myvec[i][j].dummy[0]='b';
        }
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<"Time used: "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(end - start).count()<<"ms"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are doing very little in the parallel part. Your memory performance (shared between all cores) will be a big limiting factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poor scaling in this case is mainly caused by the you not doing a large enough calculation in the parallel part. In the example code your memory performance should be the largest limiting factor and on a single desktop / mobile CPU the memory subsystem will likely be shared by all cores so you should not expect good scaling.